# update and put routes responding error 500

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I'm having difficulty setting up put and delete roots in a project the get and post methods at the same url are working fine. Currently, I'm getting an error 500 and a degree of debugging makes me think that the error is in the $http call. For the put route
 factory.update(question) is called:

```
o.update = function(question) {
        console.log('update was called')
        return $http.put('/questions', question).success(function(data){
            o.questions.push(data);
        });
    };
```

Which should call the put route in the express routes file:

```
/*UPDATE question*/
router.put('/questions', function(req, res, next){
    console.log('made it to index.js');
    var question = req.body;
    question.title = req.body.title;
    question.type = req.body.type;
    question.key = req.body.key;
    question.options = req.body.options;

    question.save(function(err){
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        } else {
            res.json(article);
        }
    });
});
```

For the delete route factory.remove(question) is called:

```
o.remove = function(question) {
        return $http.delete('/questions', question).success(function(data){
            o.questions.push(data);
        });
    }
```

Which should in turn call the delete route in the express routes file:

```
/*DELETE question*/
router.delete('/questions', function(req, res, next){
    var question = req.body;
    article.remove(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        } else {
            res.json(article);
        }
    });
});
```

It seems that in both cases the methods in the express routes file are never called which is strange because nearly identical $http requests work elsewhere in the code just fine. How do access my api?

Comment: Can you add the 500 error?

Comment: it's an internal server error

Comment: Without seeing what the error is on the server, it's hard to see what the issue is. Can you update your question with the error output?

Comment: @technicallyjosh,`DELETE http://localhost:3000/questions 500 (Internal Server Error)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:9827m @ angular.js:9628f @ angular.js:9344(anonymous function) @ angular.js:13189l.$eval @ angular.js:14401l.$digest @ angular.js:14217l.$apply @ angular.js:14506(anonymous function) @ angular.js:21443c @ angular.js:3014`

Comment: Thanks. I was referring specifically to the server side error, not the angular Promise error you get back. Can you run it locally and show what error is produced by the server itself?

Comment: I don't see one. I think it's an issue in the angular.

Comment: internal server error would not be generated from angular. It would be generated from the server side app.